# Vertical and horizontal center properties don't update after device orientation change

Tags: actionscript-3, orientation, centering, flex4.6, flex-mobile

I have a button/image that I want centered. Code below works as expected in vertical mode:

```
pauseButton.source = pause; // embedded image
pauseButton.verticalCenter = 0;
pauseButton.horizontalCenter = 0;
pauseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVideo);
```

After setting orientation to landscape mode the image stays in the same position and so is no longer centered:

```
stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT);
```

Setting verticalCenter/horizontalCenter again after orientation change doesn't make a difference. How can I force it to center.

Comment: im not too familiar with mobile dev, but are `stage.StageWidth` and `stage.StageHeight` values smart enough to change with orientation? If `stage.setOrientation()` is run before hand, could you just do  `pauseButton.x=stage.StageWidth / 2` ?

Comment: as well as `.y` too :p

Comment: Well I could calculate it but I will need to know image size and it's just not as nice. I don't know if stage.StageWidth is smart enough but all elements set with 100% width scale fine. Is there alternative to verticalCenter?

Comment: Actually, I can't use stage.StageWidth because it does not update right after the orientation change (it takes about a second). I need something that works like percent values.

Comment: Hmm I see... I know that for desktop pub, the center can dynamically transform...I just did a with `for (var i:int = 0; i < 100 ; i++){
sq.x=stage.stageWidth / 2;
sq.y=stage.stageHeight / 2;
}` and it dynamically changed position with the size of the window, without delay. Im not sure if putting this in a loop will help you at all, but I just wanted to be sure it would update accurately on my end

Comment: Actually stage width seems to work just fine now, not sure why, maybe it always did but I used this.width... btw, whats the difference between stage.width and stage.stageWidth?

Comment: `this` refers directly to whatever class/display object/whatever you are coding inside of. `stage` refers directly to the stage

Comment: and yes, that would have been the problem, as `this.stageWidth` wouldn't give you the dimensions you are looking for, because your button's center position is relative to the stage, not itself.

Comment: Add it as an answer as it's what I went with in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I know that for desktop pub, the center can dynamically transform...I just tried

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 100 ; i++){ 
sq.x=stage.stageWidth / 2; 
sq.y=stage.stageHeight / 2; }
```

and it dynamically changed position with the size of the window, without delay. Im not sure if putting this in a loop will help you at all, but I just wanted to be sure it would update accurately on my end. Works fine!